# c# HtmlAgilityPack, How to grab InnerText of all occurences of specific tag?

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack, innertext, selectnodes

As briefly explained in the title im trying to grab every InnerText of every  tag occurence and add it to a List. Here is my code aswell as my html:

HTML-Body:

```
<body cz-shortcut-listen="true">
{"draw":1,"recordsTotal":9437,"recordsFiltered":9437,"data":[["
<a target="\&quot;_blank\&quot;" href="\&quot;\/id\/115739257\&quot;">AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Factory New)&lt;\/a&gt;","</a>
<a target="\&quot;_blank\&quot;"href="\&quot;\/id\/115739257\&quot;">33.87&lt;\/a&gt;","</a>
<a target="\&quot;_blank\&quot;" href="\&quot;\/id\/115739257\&quot;">34.53&lt;\/a&gt;","</a>
<a target="\&quot;_blank\&quot;" href="\&quot;https:\/\/track.steamanalyst.com\/730\/115739257\/all\&quot;">25.9&lt;\/a&gt;","</a>
<a target="\&quot;_blank\&quot;" href="\&quot;\/id\/115739257\&quot;">164&lt;\/a&gt;","</a>
<a target="\&quot;_blank\&quot;" href="\&quot;\/id\/115739257\&quot;">-0.16&lt;\/a&gt;","</a>
<a target="\&quot;_blank\&quot;" href="\&quot;\/id\/115739257\&quot;">2.10945&lt;\/a&gt;"],["</a>
<a target="\&quot;_blank\&quot;" href="\&quot;\/id\/115734122\&quot;">AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Minimal Wear)&lt;\/a&gt;","</a>
<a target="\&quot;_blank\&quot;" href="\&quot;\/id\/115734122\&quot;">23.44&lt;\/a&gt;","</a>
<a target="\&quot;_blank\&quot;" href="\&quot;\/id\/115734122\&quot;">21.85&lt;\/a&gt;","</a>
<a target="\&quot;_blank\&quot;" href="\&quot;https:\/\/track.steamanalyst.com\/730\/115734122\/all\&quot;">17.61&lt;\/a&gt;","</a>
<a target="\&quot;_blank\&quot;" href="\&quot;\/id\/115734122\&quot;">533&lt;\/a&gt;","</a>
<a target="\&quot;_blank\&quot;" href="\&quot;\/id\/115734122\&quot;">-2.65&lt;\/a&gt;","</a>
<a target="\&quot;_blank\&quot;" href="\&quot;\/id\/115734122\&quot;">0.94387&lt;\/a&gt;"],["</a>
</body>
```

My Code:

```
List<string> Data = new List<string>();
foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@target]"))
{
    if(j <= 6)
    {
        Data.Add(node.InnerText);
        if (j == 6)
        {
            JsonDB.Add(Data[0], Data[1]);
            Data.Clear();
            j = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```

Problem with this code: node.InnerText shows a joined string of all InnerTexts of all tags in body! Basically it shows this as the first node in `doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@target]")`:

```
AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Factory New)","33.8","34.34","25.89","170",
"-1.27","2.03181"],[...
```

Answer (score 0):

All tags in body:

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@target]"))
```

Tags in the doc:

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(".//a[@target]"))
```

Comment: @Pang well this was not the problem really, but more that it shows a joined string of all innertexts as one node. Basically like this: AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Factory New)","33.8","34.34","25.89"....

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: It has to be treated like a JSON-Object before going into the HTML

```
JObject jresponse = JObject.Parse(response);
foreach (JArray row in jresponse["data"])
{
    List<string> Data = new List<string>();
    foreach (JToken entry in row)
    {
        doc.LoadHtml(entry.ToString());
        HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a[@target]");
        Data.Add(node.InnerText);
    }
}
```